# How to dissolve partitions made with networkx-metis?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, metis

We have created a graph using networkX and partitioned it using nxmetis.partition. Our question is how do we dissolve the resulting partitions to create a single group for each set of partitions?

```
PG = nxmetis.partition(G, 4, node_weight='weight', node_size='size', edge_weight='weight', tpwgts=None, ubvec=None, options=None, recursive=False)

PG
```

Result:

(10, [[3, 7], [6, 8, 9], [1, 2], [0, 4, 5]])